# Get CHMOD Value and Owner name - Unix

Tags: unix, rhel7

Their is any command to get **CHMOD** value and Owner name of a directory on Unix

expected output: `PATH/OF/DIR 777 ADMIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stat -c "%n %a %U" -- *
```

Change the wildcard to a specific directory as you wish/need.

From `man stat`:

```
-c  --format=FORMAT
          use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT

%a     access rights in octal (note '#' and '0' printf flags)
%n     file name
%U     user name of owner
```

Comment: i have list of directory scan i get for all in for loop it is possible?

Comment: You can give more than one argument to `stat`, use `xargs`, or simply use a loop to achieve that. For instance, `stat -c "%n %a %U" $HOME $HOME/.config` is perfectly valid